# Can't bind to 'property' as it is not a known property of 'selector'

Tags: javascript, angular, module, components

I am attempting to use a a sub component in a different module in my project but I am receiving the error 'Can't bind to 'message' since it isn't a known property of 'or-app-wysiwyg'. I can't see any issues with my imports, and I have checked that my the forms module has been added correctly. I believe the issue is to do with the selector but everything I have tried so far does not get rid of the error.

Wysiwyg.Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

@Component({
selector: 'or-app-wysiwyg',
templateUrl: './wysiwyg.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./wysiwyg.component.scss']
})

export class WysiwygComponent implements OnInit {

public Editor = ClassicEditor;

message = '';
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

Wysiwyg.Component.html

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="message" [editor]="Editor"></ckeditor>
```

Notes.Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { Note } from '../../../../../core/src/models/note';
import { NoteOutgoing } from 'projects/core/src/models/noteOutgoing';
import { AuthService } from 'core';
import { NotesService } from 'projects/core/src/services/note.service';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-notes',
  templateUrl: './notes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notes.component.scss'],
  })

export class NotesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() message: any;

  public Editor = ClassicEditor;
  notes: Note[] = [];
  noteOutgoing: NoteOutgoing = {message: ''};

  constructor(private noteService: NotesService, private authService: AuthService,
              private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  this.getNotes();
  }

  getNotes() {
    this.noteService.getNotesFromDB().subscribe(result => {
    this.notes = result;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

  addNote() {
    const name = this.authService.getUser().firstName + ' ' + this.authService.getUser().lastName;
    const note: Note = {name, message: this.noteOutgoing.message, date: 'date', tags: 'tag'};
    this.notes.push(note);
    console.log(this.notes);
    this.noteService.addNoteToDB(this.noteOutgoing).subscribe(() => {
    }, error => console.error(error));
    this.noteOutgoing.message = '';
  }
}
```

Note.Module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NotesComponent } from './notes.component';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { WysiwygComponent } from 'projects/core/src/components/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CKEditorModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [NotesComponent, WysiwygComponent]
})
export class NotesModule {}
```

Notes.Component.html

```
<or-app-wysiwyg [message]="message"></or-app-wysiwyg>

<button type="button" (click)="addNote()" class="btn btn- 
default">Save</button>

<div class= "card m-3" *ngFor= "let note of notes">
 Name: {{note.name}} <br> Note: {{note.message}} <br> Date: {{note.date}} <br> 
 Tags: {{note.tags}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is this:

> 'Can't bind to 'message' since it isn't a known property of 'or-app-wysiwyg'

You've not posted the offending code, but the error message suggests you are trying to bind to the `message` property on the element `or-app-wysiwyg`, which would look something like this:

```html
<or-app-wysiwyg [message]="message">
</or-app-wysiwyg>
```

In order to do this, you need to specify the `message` property as an `@Input()` property.

Wysiwyg.component.ts

```js
export class WysiwygComponent implements OnInit {
  public Editor = ClassicEditor;

  @Input() message: string;
}
```

Comment: Apologies, updated my question with the relevant code. Solved my problem thank you